# Update the color of a LED on HTML page based on AJAX call from Flask

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I'm new to web software programming and I'm facing a problem on how to update [LED indicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcun9.png) on my Flask page.

I'm using an AJAX call to get the value of my python variable to my HTML. And I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to access the *system_mode* in AJAX call and put it in the if statement at the place of *current_mode*.

- I know that I can display *system_mode* value in my HTML page by <div id="system_mode>, but I don't know how to get the value to put it in my if-statement.
- I know that I can change the value of *current_mode* by using render_template in python code, but I don't want to refresh the webpage. That's why I have been using AJAX, as it updates the page continuously.

**Python code:**

```py
mode = "startup"
@app.route('/update', methods = ['POST'])
def update():
  return jsonify({
    'system_mode': mode,
  })
```

**CSS code for one LED:**

```css
.led-green {
    background-color: #94E185;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #94E185;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #78D965;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
    
.led-gray {
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #bdbdbd;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```html
!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  >
  <!-- Your file css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          $("#system_mode").html(response["system_mode"]);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
    }, 2000);
  </script>
  <div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center my-3">
        <h3>Status</h3>
        <div class="row text-left my-3">
          <div class="col">Startup</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            {% if current_mode == "startup" %}
              <div class="led-green"></div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="led-gray"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-left my-3">
          <div class="col">Ready</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            {% if current_mode == "ready" %}
              <div class="led-green"></div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="led-gray"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-left my-3">
          <div class="col">Warning</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            {% if current_mode == "warning" %}
              <div class="led-green"></div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="led-gray"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-left my-3">
          <div class="col">Shutdown</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            {% if current_mode == "shutdown" %}
              <div class="led-green"></div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="led-gray"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-left my-3">
          <div class="col">Sleeping</div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            {% if current_mode == "sleeping" %}
              <div class="led-green"></div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="led-gray"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Hi , can you show more html code ? Also , your server will return status i.e : startup..etc and in frontend you just need to change div to green or gray ?

Comment: Hey! I added the entire relevant html code and fixed the if statement, to current_mode == startup.. etc. 
Yes, the status is being updated inside the python code. And in frontend I want to update the LED class from gray to green and back. So the user can see, what is the status at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty method (you need to specify the id of the html elem):

```
<div class="container my-5">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center my-3">
         <h3>Status</h3>
         <div class="row text-left my-3">
            <div class="col">Startup</div>
            <div class="col text-right">
               {% if current_mode == "startup" %}
               <div id="startup_id" class="led-green"></div>
               {% else %}
               <div id="startup_id" class="led-gray"></div>
               {% endif %}
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row text-left my-3">
            <div class="col">Ready</div>
            <div class="col text-right">
               {% if current_mode == "ready" %}
               <div id="ready_id" class="led-green"></div>
               {% else %}
               <div id="ready_id" class="led-gray"></div>
               {% endif %}
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- continue -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
   setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url: '/update',
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response) {
           //parse your response to understand which html elements should be updated
           system_mode = response["system_mode"];
           //clear all html elem class with:
           $("#startup_id").removeClass('led-green');
           $("#startup_id").addClass('led-gray');
           $("#ready_id").removeClass('led-green');
           $("#ready_id").addClass('led-gray');
           //continue...
           if (system_mode  == "startup") {
               $("#startup_id").addClass('led-green');
           } else if (system_mode  == "ready"){
               $("#ready_id").addClass('led-green');
          } //continue...

       },
       error: function(error) {
           console.log(error);
       }
   })}, 2000);
</script>
{% if current_mode %}
<div class="led-green"></div>
{% else %}
<div class="led-gray"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) This solution worked, I only had to add removeClass(); before if statements and then one for each condition, to be able to change from gray to green.